# Reading JSON in c# - concatenating some node values into string and others comma separated

Tags: c#, json

I have the following example record in JSON and using C#, I need to convert this to a comma delimited string. Where the node is "primitiveValue" it will be comma delimited, but where the node is "conversionPathValue" i need to concatenate the descendant "nodeValue" values together.

```
  [
   {
    "primitiveValue": "20130122"
   },
   {
    "conversionPathValue": [
     {
      "interactionType": "CLICK",
      "nodeValue": "MET"
     },
     {
      "interactionType": "CLICK",
      "nodeValue": "MET"
     },
     {
      "interactionType": "CLICK",
      "nodeValue": "MET"
     },
     {
      "interactionType": "CLICK",
      "nodeValue": "MET"
     },
     {
      "nodeValue": "(none)"
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "primitiveValue": "1"
   },
   {
    "primitiveValue": "3857.0"
   }
  ]
```

For the above JSON extract I need this to be converted to one line string as follows:

'20130122','MET-MET-MET-MET-(none)','1','3857.0'

The JSON output has many records so I need to loop through each record to do this.

What's the best way to concatenate the conversionpathvalue elements seperately to the primitiveValue elements and join together per row? Also, there may be more than one set of conversionpathValue elements in the same row, so these need to be separate.

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Servicestack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text)'s `JsonSerializer`.`ServiceStack.Text` is an independent, dependency-free serialization library that contains all of ServiceStack's text processing functionality, including:

```
    1.  JsonSerializer
    2.  TypeSerializer (JSV-Format)
    3.  CsvSerializer
    4.  T.Dump extension method
    5.  StringExtensions - Xml/Json/Csv/Url encoding, BaseConvert, etc.
    6.  Stream, Reflection, List, DateTime, etc extensions and utils
```

**Using Structs to Customize JSON**

This makes it possible to customize the serialization routine and provide an even more compact wire format.

E.g. Instead of using a JSON object to represent a point

```
{ Width=20, Height=10 }
```

You could use a `struct` and reduce it to just:

```
"20x10"
```

By overriding `ToString()` and providing a `static Size ParseJson()` method:

```
public struct Size
{
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Width + "x" + Height;
    }

    public static Size ParseJson(string json)
    {
        var size = json.Split('x');
        return new Size { 
            Width = double.Parse(size[0]), 
            Height = double.Parse(size[1]) 
        };
    }
}
```

Which would change it to the more compact JSON output:

```
new Size { Width = 20, Height = 10 }.ToJson() // = "20x10"
```

That allows you to deserialize it back in the same way:

```
var size = "20x10".FromJson<Size>();
```

**Using Custom IEnumerable class to serialize a JSON array**

In addition to using a `Struct` you can optionally use a custom `C# IEnumerable` type to provide a strong-typed wrapper around a JSON array:

```
public class Point : IEnumerable
{
    double[] points = new double[2];

    public double X 
    {
        get { return points[0]; }
        set { points[0] = value; }
    }


  public double Y
    {
        get { return points[1]; }
        set { points[1] = value; }
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var point in points) 
            yield return point;
    }
}

Which serializes the Point into a compact JSON array:

new Point { X = 1, Y = 2 }.ToJson() // = [1,2]
```

Hope you can do your task using this as a reference. Most important point to note is that `Servicestack's JsonSerializer` is the fastest on planet after `protocol-buffers.`

Comment: thanks for you comment, but i've been using JSON.net and would prefer to keep with that, rather than adding another library

Comment: @AlistairMcIntyre Servicestack is the fastest library..I recommend using it.